# Pass a value to multiple actions with tempdata

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, action, tempdata

I want to get an *ID* through one action and pass it to two other actions with temp data

How can I pass a value to **multiple** actions?

Comment: Why would you pass from one action to another? If there's functionality contained in the other two actions that the first one should invoke, then that functionality should be moved to a method (or multiple methods) that the first action can invoke.

Answer (score 1):

When you want keep Tempdata, you need use `TempData.Peek` and `TempData.Keep`. You can refer my sample code to use it.

If you don't want keep data, you just get data like `getdata3`. You can get value when first request.

#### Sample Code

```
    public string setdata(string data)
    {
        TempData["data"] = data;
        
        return "success";
    }
    public string getdata1()
    {
        TempData.Peek("data");
        if (TempData["data"] == null)
        {
            return "not set";
        }
        else {
            TempData.Keep("data");
            return TempData["data"].ToString();
        }
    }
    public string getdata2()
    {
        TempData.Peek("data");
        if (TempData["data"] == null)
        {
            return "not set";
        }
        else
        {
            TempData.Keep("data");
            return TempData["data"].ToString();
        }
    }
    public string getdata3()
    {
        if (TempData["data"] == null)
        {
            return "not set";
        }
        else
        {
            return TempData["data"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

[image]