# TempData not working properly with AJAX calls

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET MVC 6 project, from a standard MVC controller I consume an endpoint which returns a view. I also have a script file, which in  `$(document).ready(function ()` executes 3 AJAX calls, which run truly in parallel.
These 3 AJAX calls consume 3 endpoints in the same controller - the endpoints make separate async HTTP requests to other projects, cache the fetched data using `TempData`, then invoke the `Keep();` method to save the data for the next requests and finally return a partial view, each. The purpose of the calls is to update the view dynamically.

The problem is the following:
Since the AJAX calls run in parallel, the consuming of the endpoints starts simultaneously. In my case 2 of the calls finish almost the same, while the 3rd one transfers more information and is late with the response.
And even though the previous calls are completed successfully and cached their data in `TempData`, while debugging the 3rd (longest) call, when I put breakpoint to the TempData object **it does not contain the data from the previous calls**.

I tried many things, nothing worked, except if I chain (make them sequential) the AJAX calls to be one after the other - 1st invokes 2nd, which invokes the 3rd one. Then the `TempData` object is successfully persisted.

I also checked in the case of chaining AJAX calls (where the data IS persisted), if different threads are consuming the endpoints and indeed different threads are used. So, the `TempData` object IS thread safe.

Last but not least, some elements from the view, on click invoke controller endpoints which return a new view. If I debug the invocation process, again the `TempData` does not contain all the data, but only the data from the last call.

I ran out of ideas, does anyone know how to tackle this issue?

Comment: After further testing, I found out that the information persists only for the AJAX call, which finishes last. And between the AJAX calls the information is not persisted.

Answer (score 1):

[I have test this before,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69579120/7687666)  TempData is meant to be a short-lived store for data across two subsequent HTTP requests.

As you mentioned, the 3rd http request, the value of TempData was gone. It is by design. [TempData only works during the current and subsequent request (1st and 2 nd)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71868131/7687666).

For more details, you can refer [this popular answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21254178/7687666).

If you want to store values persistently, we recommend using Session or Redis or DB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is something that I missed to mention.
I want to point that after I set and get the information from TempData, I invoke the Keep() method in every call. Still the problem persists.

Comment: @Andrеw Brief answer, you should use `var  data =  TempData.Peek("key");`, instead of  `var data= TempData["key"]`, it will remove the value after reading it.

Comment: @Andrеw Could you kindly check this `var  data =  TempData.Peek("key")`, I am waiting for your test result.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately I just tested with Peek. I cannot share any code since it is sensitive data but it goes like this:
``var cachedData = TempData.Peek(myNumber) as string;``
``var realData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyDTO>(cachedData);``
``TempData.Keep();``
Still, the last from the 3 ajax calls only saves the temp data.